# How to fix the error; 'Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tether

I'm using Bootstrap V4 and the following error is logged in the console;

> Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether
>   (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)

I have tried to remove the error by installing Tether but it hasn't worked. I have 'installed' Tether by including the following lines of code;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/css/tether.min.css">
<script src="http://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Have I 'installed' tether correctly?

Can anyone help me remove this error?

If you wish to view the error on my site, please click [here](https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk) and load your console.

Comment: Hi, can you post the code you use? would be better if you could put the code in jsfiddle or somewhere else.

Comment: There's no real code to post but if you visit www.atlasestateagents.co.uk and view the console you will see the javascript error?

Comment: I used these exact lines of code and they removed the error for me in V3, for anyone wondering about that version.

Comment: @MichaelLB, instead of link to your website, I'd recommend to put some code-snippets here, within the question itself, is your website will be updated, and it will lose the actuality.

Comment: Solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431612/using-bootstrap-4-with-angular-4

Answer (score 245, accepted):

#### For Bootstrap 4 stable:

Since beta Bootstrap 4 doesn't depend on Tether but **Popper.js**. All scripts (**must be** in this order):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

See the current [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js) for the newest script versions.

---

#### Only Bootstrap 4 alpha:

Bootstrap 4 **alpha** needs [Tether](http://tether.io/), so you need to include `tether.min.js` **before** you include `bootstrap.min.js`, eg.

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Fixed, thank you! However, fixing that lead to a new warning, maybe for a new question? `mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create'`

Comment: Great! I *think* the error you're getting is coming from the `bootstrap.min.js` library. Does it still show up if you comment it out. Yeah, I'd post a new question if Google doesn't have a solution. :)

Comment: Consider using npmcdn to link to packages published on npm, as some folks tend to remove the build/dist files from github. `https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/` and `https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2/dist/`

Comment: but its strange , http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/ doesn't says anything about it

Comment: It does on version aplha.3. Just had this error. I believe tether is now downloaded as a package and not included anymore. So you'll have to include this script aswell.

Comment: Why not just bundle it with the download?  Would that make too much sense?

Answer (score 20):

If you're using Webpack:

1. Set up bootstrap-loader as described in docs;
2. Install tether.js via npm;
3. Add tether.js to the webpack ProvidePlugin plugin.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
plugins: [
        <... your plugins here>,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "window.Tether": 'tether'
        })
    ]
```

[Source](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/issues/48)

Comment: Is this all you need. I'm doing this and its not working.

Comment: As I mentioned on the Github issue, newer versions of Bootstrap (e.g. 4.0.0-alpha.6) are now looking for "Tether" instead of "window.Tether".

Answer (score 18):

If you are using npm and browserify:

```
// es6 imports
import tether from 'tether';
global.Tether = tether;

// require
global.Tether = require('tether');
```

Answer (score 14):

Personally I use small subset of Bootstrap functionality and don't need to attach Tether.

This should help:

```
window.Tether = function () {
  throw new Error('Your Bootstrap may actually need Tether.');
};
```

Comment: so what do you propose, to cut these lines? not good, as you shouldn't modify *vendors* and *third party* libs, it will prevent you doing updates later. If you don't use these Bootstrap components as you say - why would you need Tether... so I'm not really understanding the value of your input.

Comment: Tether warning is show even, if you don't use bootstrap functionality that requires Tether. My solution hides annoying message in the console.

Comment: And this change is not updating 3rdparty or vendor scripts. You can add it above <script src="bootstrap.js">

Comment: I don't really understand you, why not just one-liner then, alike `window.Tether = window.Tether || {};`? Plus, there's caveat in your solution, that it can wipe already defined dependency in a global scope, if the module will be loaded before your thing is executed.

Comment: This is hack for a alpha version of Bootstrap. I don't see reason to be picky :-)
If developer don't want to use Tether, wiping already defined dependency is not a case. And in my opinion `window.Tether = window.Tether || {};` is worse because it will throw `Tether is not a function`, instead of meaningful error.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to avoid the error message and you are not using Bootstrap tool tips, you can define window.Tether before loading Bootstrap.

```
<script>
  window.Tether = {};
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked well for me... in my case I am using angular with bootstrap. Thanks!

Comment: Worked, I added same in my file, it's working fine now. Thanks for this Idea.
```window.Tether = {};
define(['tether'], function (Tether) {
    return window.Tether = Tether;
});```

Answer (score 8):

You should done my guideline:
1. Add bellow source into Gemfile

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.1.0'
end
```

2. Run command:

   bundle install
3. Add this line after jQuery in application.js.

   //= require jquery
       //= require tether
4. Restart rails server.

Answer (score 7):

Install tether via npm like below

```
npm install tether --save-dev
```

then add tether to your html above bootstrap like below

```
<script src="node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: or **bower** like this `bower install tether --save-dev`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `npm install tether --save` instead of `--save-dev`? It will be needed also in production.

Answer (score 7):

For webpack I resolved this with `webpack.config.js`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  "window.jQuery": "jquery",
  Tether: 'tether'
})
```

Answer (score 5):

An additional note. If you check uncompressed javascript file, you will find the condition:

```
if(window.Tether === undefined) {
     throw new Error('Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether)')
}
```

So the error message contains the required information.

> You can download the archive from that [**link**](http://github.hubspot.com/tether/).

Uncompressed version:

https://rawgit.com/HubSpot/tether/master/src/js/tether.js
https://rawgit.com/HubSpot/tether/master/dist/css/tether.css

Answer (score 3):

Using webpack I used this in `webpack.config.js`:

```
var plugins = [

    ...

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        'window.Tether': 'tether',
        tether: 'tether',
        Tether: 'tether'
    })
];
```

It seems like `Tether` was the one it was looking for:

```
var Tooltip = function ($) {

  /**
   * Check for Tether dependency
   * Tether - http://tether.io/
   */
  if (typeof Tether === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I would suggest that you edit your answer to remove the unused line `tether: 'tether',`

Comment: You are right, but as an example I think it illustrates the fact that exact naming is required.

Comment: Imagine the confused face of the developer when opening tether.to, trying to find there a solution for this issue. :D I fixed it by adding `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue with requirejs using the newest boostrap 4 build. I ended up just defining:

```
<script>
  window.Tether = {};
</script>
```

in my html head tag to fool bootstrap's check. I then added a second require statement just before the require that loads my app, and subsequently, my bootstrap dependency:

```
require(['tether'], function (Tether) {
  window.Tether = Tether;
});

require([
  "app",
], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

Using both of these in tandem and you should have no problem using current bootstrap 4 alpha build.

Answer (score 2):

Works for generator-aspnetcore-spa and bootstrap 4.

```
// ===== file: webpack.config.vendor.js =====    
module.exports = (env) => {
...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', 
                                    jQuery: 'jquery',
                                    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                                    'window.Tether': 'tether',
                                    tether: 'tether', 
                                    Tether: 'tether' }), 
// Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package 
// (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            ...
        ]
};
```

Comment: Enough only three: ...new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            Tether: 'tether'
        }), ...

Answer (score 1):

For webpack 1 or 2 with Bootstrap 4 you need

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: 'jquery',
   jQuery: 'jquery',
   Tether: 'tether'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Brunch, you can add this at the end of your `brunch-config.js`:

```
npm: {
    enabled: true,
    globals: {
        $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', 'Tether': 'tether'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use require.js AMD loader:

```
// path config
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/core.js',
    tether: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min',
    bootstrap: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min',
  },
  shim: {
    bootstrap: {
      deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
});

//async loading
requirejs(['tether'], function (Tether) {
  window.Tether = Tether;
  requirejs(['bootstrap']);
});
```

Comment: This really helped me. I was stuck on this for ages - didn't realise you could nest the require calls. Upvote for you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

For you Laravel Mix users out there running Bootstrap4, you will need to run

```
npm installer tether --save
```

Then update you `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` to load Tether and bring it to the window object.

Here is what mine looks like: (Note I also had to run `npm install popper.js --save`)

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.Tether = require('tether');
require('bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 0):

### UMD/AMD solution

For those guys, who are doing it through **UMD**, and compile via `require.js`, there is a laconic solution.

In the module, which requires `tether` as the dependency, which loads `Tooltip` as UMD, in front of module definition, just put short snippet on definition of Tether:

```
// First load the UMD module dependency and attach to global scope
require(['tether'], function(Tether) {
    // @todo: make it properly when boostrap will fix loading of UMD, instead of using globals
    window.Tether = Tether; // attach to global scope
});

// then goes your regular module definition
define([
    'jquery',
    'tooltip',
    'popover'
], function($, Tooltip, Popover){
    "use strict";
    //...
    /*
        by this time, you'll have window.Tether global variable defined,
        and UMD module Tooltip will not throw the exception
    */
    //...
});
```

This short snippet at the very beginning, actually may be put on any higher level of your application, the most important thing - to invoke it before actual usage of `bootstrap` components with `Tether` dependency.

```
// ===== file: tetherWrapper.js =====
require(['./tether'], function(Tether) {
    window.Tether = Tether; // attach to global scope
    // it's important to have this, to keep original module definition approach
    return Tether;
});

// ===== your MAIN configuration file, and dependencies definition =====
paths: {
    jquery: '/vendor/jquery',
    // tether: '/vendor/tether'
    tether: '/vendor/tetherWrapper'  // @todo original Tether is replaced with our wrapper around original
    // ...
},
shim: { 
     'bootstrap': ['tether', 'jquery']       
}
```

---

**UPD:** In Boostrap 4.1 Stable they replaced *Tether*, with [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/), see [the documentation on usage](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js).

Answer (score 0):

To add to @adilapapaya's answer. For `ember-cli` users specifically, install `tether` with

```
bower install --save tether
```

and then include it in your `ember-cli-build.js` file before bootstrap, like so:

```
// tether (bootstrap 4 requirement)
app.import('bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js');

// bootstrap
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-flex.scss');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

And if using webpack, you will need the expose plugin. In your webpack.config.js, add this loader

```
{
   test: require.resolve("tether"),
   loader: "expose?$!expose?Tether"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it.
I'm on rails 5.1.0rc1

Make sure to add require jquery and tether inside your application.js file they must be at the very top like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
```

Just make sure to have tether installed

Answer (score 0):

**Method #1**: Download from [Here](https://github.com/HubSpot/tether/tree/master/dist/js) and insert it to your projects, or
 **Method #2**: use below code before your bootstrap script source:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the instructions in the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start):

> Copy-paste the stylesheet `<link>` into your `<head>` before all other
>   stylesheets to load our CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

> Add our JavaScript plugins, jQuery, and Tether near the end of your
>   pages, right before the closing  tag. Be sure to place jQuery
>   and Tether first, as our code depends on them. While we use jQuery’s
>   slim build in our docs, the full version is also supported.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and i solved it by including jquery-3.1.1.min before including any js and it worked like a charm. Hope it helps.