# Like comment Ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using the "Acts As Votable" gem in my application because I want to allow my user to like and dislike comments. It has been working good so far, but now I want to implement Ajax to improve the user interface.

This is my code:

**routes.rb**:

```
resources :articles do
    member do
      put "like", to: "articles#upvote"
    end
    resources :comments do
      member do
        get "like", to: "comments#upvote"
        get "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
      end
    end
  end
```

comments_controller.rb:

```
def upvote
    if @comment.upvote_from current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def downvote
    if @comment.downvote_from current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

_comment.html.erb:

```
<span class="like-comment">
      <%= link_to like_article_comment_url(@article, comment), method: :get, remote: true do %>
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="thumbs-up"> <%= comment.get_upvotes.size %></span>
      <% end %>
    </span>
    <p class="dislike-comment">
      <%= link_to dislike_article_comment_url(@article, comment), method: :get, remote: true do %>
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down" id="thumbs-down"> <%= comment.get_downvotes.size %></span>
      <% end %>
```

upvote.js.erb:

```
$('#thumbs-up').replaceWith("<%= j render comment.get_upvotes.size %>");
```

downvote.js.erb:

```
$('#thumbs-down').replaceWith("<%= j render comment.get_downvotes.size %>");
```

The problem is it doesn't update the number of like/dislike when I click the like/dislike button. However, when I refresh the page, it updates the number of like/dislike. I don't know why the view doesn't update the number of like/dislike. Moreover, I tried to change the file to upvote.erb.js/downvote.erb.js as other people suggested but the problem is still there.

*Updated:
**When I opened the network console in firefox, I saw 500 internal server error when I clicked the like/dislike butto. I searched all the problem related with that error, but still couldn't figure what is wrong with my code.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename file from .js.erb to .erb.js.
That is because your ruby code has to be executed first

Comment: Thanks for your quicky reply, but it doesnt work for me in this situation. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery on the front end, you could either rename your javascript files to .erb.js instead of .js.erb to prioritize the erb preprocessing first, or you could create an endpoint to retrieve that data so you can avoid bugs where maybe your ruby model code does not break javascript on the front end, its also best practice to make that data available over an endpoint in general.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried it, but it doesnt work me. :(

Comment: When you view page source, what do you see on the #('#thumbs-down").replaceWith() line?

Comment: Also is there any info in the javascript console?

Comment: `<a data-remote="true" data-method="get" href="http://localhost:3000/articles/23/comments/45/like">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="thumbs-up"> 0</span>
</a>`
Javascript Console: Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)
 tooltip.self-ff495cd6932165d4adceb3a8baec7340536f4d26b2fa14cd202e651ccc7f513a.js:24:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Not sure if this is gonna fix everything, but have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h

When you fix that, let me know what you see in the javascript console.

Comment: yes, I saw that post 2 days ago. But the thing is I am integrating my bootstrap 4 by using the gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'. And, I tried to add the script 
`<script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap -->` in my application.html.erb, but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you put the script before your bootstrap or after? I guess what I am think is that bootstrap is throwing up and breaking the javascript on your page.

Comment: Also could you show us your javascript logic for when the user clicks the upvote or downvote button?

Comment: I opened my network console in firefox, and when I clicked the like button, it showed that I got the 500 internal server error, still haven't known what is wrong with my code.

Comment: That tells me that your backend code is breaking. Whats the stacktrace on the rails side?

Comment: Also it might be helpful to see your models.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the routes for upvote/downvote?

And you should try:

```
$('#thumbs-up').text("<%= j render comment.get_upvotes.size %>");
$('#thumbs-down').text("<%= j render comment.get_downvotes.size %>");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I defined the route for them. Actually, everything works fine. The problem arises when I add ajax to them. I tried .text as you suggested but it still doesnt work. :(