# What is the best way to load Bootstrap with an ES6 import?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, import, ecmascript-6

I recently switched from using Require.js to using WebPack with Babel. In the past I would use the CommonJS standard in my JS modules, like this

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Since Bootstrap is a jQuery plugin, jQuery would load first and bootstrap would load second.

Babel allows me to use ES6 `import` statements. But when I write

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

I get the error that `$ is undefined`. Bootstrap assumes that `window.$` is present, but `import` does not pollute the window object, which is a good thing, but leaves my code like this:

```
// legacy loading for bootstrap
var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
require('bootstrap');
// the rest of the imports
import _ from 'underscore';
```

There must be a better solution. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try: 
    import jQuery from 'jquery' ;
    const $ = jQuery ;

Comment: This is how I have been including bootstrap 4 off late https://gist.github.com/vishim/9c3e1b06a8f513c923e5187490d8f917

Comment: If you're using browserify, maybe use https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-shim ?

Answer (score 28):

### If you have `Webpack` in your build...

...you'll need to work with **Webpack's provide plugin**.  Since the error is that `jQuery is not defined` we will *define/provide* it with the plugin :

#### In the `webpack configuration` :

```
// webpack.config.js
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery'
  })
]
...
```

#### Now, in our `ES6/2015 module` :

```
// main.js
...
// jquery is required for bootstrap
import $ from 'jquery'

// bootstrap
import 'bootstrap'

// bootstrap css 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
...
```

**Reference :** https://2017-sparkler.rhcloud.com/2017/02/01/bootstrap-in-webpack-es6-2015-project/

Good Luck.

Answer (score 8):

### Bootstrap 4 Solution

Bootstrap 4 has two dependencies: jQuery and [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/).

1. Install necessary packages:

   ```
   npm install jquery popper.js bootstrap --save
   ```
2. In your app, import like so:

   ```
   import 'bootstrap';
   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
   ```
3. If you want to use `$` globally for jQuery, add this to your webpack config (this is `webpack.base.conf.js` for me):

   ```
   plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: 'jquery'
     })
   ]
   ```

Comment: what about  latest boostrap 3.*?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers here say to use the Webpack's `ProvidePlugin`.

As of 2020 and `bootstrap v4.4.1`, you do not need to use that plugin.

Bootstrap defines both `jquery` and `popper.js` as peer dependencies, so you just install them together with `bootstrap`:

```
npm i -S bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

And use them in your code, e.g.:

```js
import "bootstrap";
import $ from "jquery";

$(() => {
    $(".element-with-tooltip").tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **Bootstrap 4 alpha**, you will need `tether` as well as `jQuery`. Imports are discussed here: [How to fix the error; 'Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h)

Answer (score 0):

```
import './wrappers/jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
```

and in `wrappers/jquery.js`:

```
import jquery from 'jquery;
window.jQuery = window.$ = jquery;
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these are old answers and in 2023 `import 'bootstrap';` didn't work for me. Instead I had to do:

In package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.6.3",
  "bootstrap4": "npm:bootstrap@^4.6.2"
}
```

In your JS

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap4/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
```