# importing jquery in index.js and saving it as window.$ doesn't work in other components

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

In my app I import jquery in my index.js and save it on window in order to make it global like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import $ from "jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min";
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min'
window.jQuery = window.$ = $;

ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

On another file i'm trying to use jquery in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const audio = document.getElementById("player"); 
    const popover = <div>bla bla bla</div>
    $('#player').popover({title: popover, html: true, placement: "bottom"}); 
})
```

but I get an error that *'$' is not defined*. Why it isn't becoming global?

Comment: Did you try using ``window.$`` instead? Ecmascript modules scopes everything locally unless you refer them from global object like window

Comment: @SachinSingh yes I did. but then I get 'window.$ is not a function'

Comment: Why do you want to set $ on window? You should import $ inside any of your files and use it as a ES module instead. Or if you want global jQuery reference for any reason then add a separate script tag and use the CDN version.

Comment: @SachinSingh if I use it in every module, I get an error saying "jquery_dist_jquery_slim_min__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...)(...).popover is not a function". I can try to import it via script tag, but I want all external global libraries to be administrated with imports in one place and bundle it in one file

Comment: @SachinSingh and I also want to know why this doesn't work :)

Comment: Hmm! Not sure what the problem is. I tried it myself and it seems to work. Can you check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452086/what-is-the-best-way-to-load-bootstrap-with-an-es6-import

This should hopefully solve your problem

Comment: If above solution doesn't work. Would you mind sharing a sample code of what you're trying to do. A small repo would work.