# bootstrap carousel not displaying images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my carousel is not displaying images .I have 3 images stored in folder name images.I am using bootstrap 4 ,let me know what is wrong.I also wanted to know if I am suppose to insert images below 900*500 resolution.

1-ronald.jpg of 634 * 424 then

2-messi.jpg of 594 *432 and last

3-pogba.jpg of 620 * 348 resolution

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <style type="text/css">


.carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img {
        padding-top:35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 750px;  
   
}



.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;


}
#carousel
{
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img data-src="images/ronaldo1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="images/pogba.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img data-src="images/messi.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: what is your last 'script' tag ???

Comment: on running you snippet i see Bootstrap tooltips require Tether error, have you included the required file for tether?

Comment: nothing is there in the script tags.It is just opened and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<img>` tags

```
 <img data-src="images/pogba.jpg" alt="Second slide">
```

change `data-src` to just `src`.

```
 <img src="images/pogba.jpg" alt="Second slide">
```

That way the markup can find the image.

`data-` is used for storing plain data text.

Check [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fy9rfg22/).

Comment: hey worked fine Thanks , but the images appear to the extreme top left corner any idea how to bring them in center.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/fy9rfg22/1/ added a new CSS rule. Also if you want to center them vertically too, you can get rid of the "height" in the first rule, so it fits the image automatically.

Comment: I have edited css to get rounded corners on images.I have added border-radius but it doesn't apply to the top side of the image.Any help you can give.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Try including the tether.min.js script before you include the
>   bootstrap.min.js script.

[How to fix the error; 'Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h)

Answer (score 0):

@yuriy636 solution is working fine and if not working yet then check image permission. may be some time if file dont have permission then browser unable to load that file.