# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/) at bootstrap.min.js:7

Tags: laravel, tether, min.js

I am beginner in laravel, so can anyone help me to figure this out ? 
In /public/app.blade.php  look like this

```html
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix the error; 'Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h)

Answer (score 0):

Just add tether dependency in your code.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or download the `Tether` locally from

> https://github.com/HubSpot/tether

add add to your project

```
<script src="path/to/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer just try that way keep tether before bootstrap