# Using Bootstrap 4 with Angular 4

Tags: angular, tether

After installing Bootstrap 4, in Angular 4, I am getting an error :
[Script Loader] Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/).
I tried installing tether, passing tether CDN but it dint help.

Comment: Show us your code ? Based on what you say, it should work. Make sure to include Tether BEFORE Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the reference to tether.min.css in your angular-cli.json file

```
styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/css/tether.min.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, I came across this site https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-Bootstrap-4-Tutorial. It helped.I added tether.min.js before bootstrap.min.js and that fixed the error.

Comment: Incorrect answer, Bootstrap 4 using popper, not tether

Answer (score 1):

Watch Video or Follow the step

[Install bootstrap 4 in angular 4 / angular 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j142hRUnB_Y)

There is two way to include bootstrap in your project 

1) add CDN Link in index.html file 
2) Install bootstrap using npm

I recommended you following 2 methods that are installed bootstrap using npm because its available on your project directory

1) install bootstrap using npm

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

after the installation of Bootstrap 4, we Need two More javascript Package that is Jquery and Popper.js without these two package bootstrap is not complete

2) Install JQUERY

```
npm install jquery --save
```

3) Install Popper.js

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

Now Bootstrap is Install on you Project Directory inside **node_modules** Folder

open **.angular-cli.json** this file are available on you angular directory  open that file and add the path of bootstrap, jquery, and popper.js files inside **styles[]** and **scripts[]** path see the below example

```
"styles": [   
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [  

    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  ],
```

**Note:** Don't change a sequence of js file it should be like this

**Now Bootstrap Working fine Now**