# How to fix the Error; "SyntaxError: Identifier 'getScrollParents' has already been declared; Bootstrap tooltips require Tether;

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid, tether

I have tried to remove the issue by installing tether.js and utils.js, it seems when I fix one error 2 more pop up.

Here is a link to a similar post but I'm having a slightly different issue, this issue that I'm having spawned out of the previous problem.

Is there anything I can do? Or should I just revert back to boostrap3

[how to fix the error bootstrap tooltips require tether HTTP github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567939/how-to-fix-the-error-error-bootstrap-tooltips-require-tether-http-github-h/48855088?noredirect=1#comment84713688_48855088)

```
tether.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'getScrollParents' has already been declared
    at tether.js:1

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)
    at bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.0.0:7
    at bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.0.0:7
    at bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.0.0:7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

https://forums.asp.net/t/2121600.aspx?Uncaught+Error+Bootstrap+tooltips+require+Tether

i changed the line

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/node_modules/tether/src/js/tether.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

using tether.min.js fix your problem