# How to add Tether in Aurelia-CLI to use with Bootstrap 4

Tags: requirejs, aurelia, tether

I am trying to add [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) to `Aurelia`. I can only get the `CSS` to work but the `bootstrap.js` requires `Tether` and I can't get it included, since I keep getting this error in the console:

```
Bootstrap tooltips require Tether
```

I tried something along this

```
"jquery",
"Tether",
{
  "name": "tether",
  "path": "../node_modules/tether/dist",
  "main": "js/tether.min",
  "exports": "Tether",
  "resources": [
    "css/tether.css"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
  "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
  "deps": ["tether", "jquery"],
  "exports": "$",
  "resources": [
    "css/bootstrap.css"
  ]
},
```

It does bundle, but it's still complaining about the missing `Tether`. 
I read on another [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34682297/1212166<code>)  that I have to makeTether`available globally which could be done via`requirejs.config.js` with this

```
define(['lib/tether.min'], function(tether) {
    window.Tether = tether;    
});
```

but there's no such config with `Aurelia`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some more time spent on this, I believe that I came up with something working. I don't see anymore errors and I am now able to use `Bootstrap tooltip`, so I will assume this is the working solution.

All the changes were made inside the `aurelia.json` configuration file, as the following:

```
"prepend": [
   "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
   "node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
   "scripts/require.js"
],
"dependencies": [
    ...
    "aurelia-templating-binding",
    "jquery",
    "tether",
    {
        "name": "bootstrap",
        "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
        "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
        "deps": ["jquery", "tether"],
        "exports": "$",
        "resources": [
            "css/bootstrap.css"
        ]
    },
    ...
```

So basically, I just had to add it to the `prepend` to get it working. Also note that adding `tether` inside the `deps[]` array has no effect (probably because `Tether` is now global with the `prepend`), but I like to see it there as a reminder that it's a dependencies anyway.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @Paul-Sebastian, it's probably better to remove `tether` from showing up in the `deps` of `Bootstrap` to remove possibility of double inclusion. Basically this is the updated code:

```
"tether",
{
    "name": "bootstrap",
    "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
    "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
    "deps": ["jquery"],
    "exports": "$",
    "resources": [
        "css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
 },
```

**EDIT #2**

There is now also an `append` section that just got added to `Aurelia-CLI` to help with Legacy Library with Plugins. The section reads as the following:

> #### A Very Stubborn Legacy Library With Plugins
>
> Some legacy libraries may support plugins which you also want included in your bundle. In some cases these plugins depend on a
>   global object defined by the main library, so it is important that the
>   plugins exist later in the bundle than the main library scripts. These
>   plugins can go in the `append` section, which works exactly the same
>   as the `prepend` section but the scripts are appended to the end of
>   the bundle, after all other items. Like the prepend section all items
>   are relative to the project folder, not the src.

Comment: Well, keeping tether inside "deps" also makes aurelia-cli bundler bundle/trace those deps before bootstrap. Otherwise, this order would be random (`au run` output):
`Tracing tether...
 Tracing jquery...
 Tracing bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min...`

Comment: Not sure to fully understand your comment, are you suggesting to remove `tether` from `dependencies` to remove random tracing?

Comment: I actually wasn't but you're right. Prepend and deps both pull in tether but in different scopes! So you're right, it's better that we remove the deps listing to fix double inclusion of the same definitions. Am I right?

Comment: Tested a few possibilities and I can't get it working without `Tether` being in the `prepend` section. Also removing it from `dependencies` cause the bundling to fail. I got mixed up with `deps` and `dependencies`, but I get what you mean now and yes I removed it from `deps` and it still works, that is the only thing that I could remove out of it. Will add this in my answer, thanks

Comment: Great! Maybe someone more knowledgeable can explain why tether needs to be added to the prepend step but until then, this will serve as a good answer.