# Bootstrap 4 Beta importing Popper.js with Webpack 3.x throws Popper is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, aurelia, bootstrap-4

So `Bootstrap 4 Beta` is out... yay! However Tether was replaced with `Popper.js` for tooltip (and other features), but with that I see a new error thrown in the console to advise me of the change to `Popper.js`:

```
Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js
```

Seems easy enough, I went and updated my `webpack.config.js` (the entire config can be seen [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Realtime-TODO-Aurelia-Auth-RethinkDB/blob/master/client-ts-wp/webpack.config.js)) and Bootstrap then started working (the only change I did was to replace Tether with Popper):

```
plugins: [
new ProvidePlugin({
  'Promise': 'bluebird',
  '$': 'jquery',
  'jQuery': 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  'window.$': 'jquery',
  Popper: 'popper.js' 
}),
```

I also did the `import 'bootstrap'` in my `main.ts` file.

However I now have another problem (which I did not have with Tether), a new error is thrown in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Popper is not a constructor
```

If I try to debug in Chrome, I do have `Popper` loaded as an Object (which is why Bootstrap stopped complaining) as you can see in the print screen below. [image]

Finally to include all my code. I use Bootstrap tooltip with a simple custom element built with `Aurelia` and `TypeScript` (which used to work with previous Bootstrap alpha 6 and Tether)

```
import {inject, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@customAttribute('bootstrap-tooltip')
@inject(Element)
export class BootstrapTooltip {
  element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  bind() {
    $(this.element).tooltip();
  }

  unbind() {
    $(this.element).tooltip('dispose');
  }
}
```

Looks like I did not import `Popper` correctly, if so then what is the best way to achieve that with `Webpack 3.x`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

While browsing [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0). I actually found a section about `Webpack` which explains how to install it correctly. Following the [Bootstrap - installing with Webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/) documentation, the answer is to simply modify the `webpack.config.js` with the following:

```
plugins: [
  // ...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
  // ...
]
```

and let's not forget to `import` it in the `main.ts`

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

and voilà! We are back in business :)

Comment: hey guys! How can i do the same using aurelia.json ?

Comment: @JhonatasKleinkauff the question here was for WebPack only, but for `Aurelia-CLI`, have you tried something along the line of the previous Tether import: [aurelia-cli-to-use-with-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432962/how-to-add-tether-in-aurelia-cli-to-use-with-bootstrap-4/39461325#39461325)

Comment: @ghiscoding yeah i know, heres what im looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816118/bootstrap-4-error-bootstrap-dropdown-require-popper-js-with-aurelia-cli-and-r/45816956#comment78591799_45816956

Comment: @JhonatasKleinkauff very similar to previous answer with Tether then, the only difference I see is to use the UMD path. Anyhow, glad you found your answer for the CLI :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Webpack Do this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default; // pay attention to "default"
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 6):

In `bootstrap": "^4.1.1"` no need to import `jquery` and `popper.js` because those plugins will be already included when 'bootstrap' or bootstrap's plugins imported individually.

> **Notice** that if you chose to import plugins individually, you must also
>   install exports-loader

No need to require files `require('exports-loader?file ... ');` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader) because this will be taken care automatically by just installing `$ npm install exports-loader --save-dev`

```
import 'bootstrap'; // Import all plugins at once

//
// Or, import plugins individually
//
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/alert';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/button';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/carousel';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/collapse';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/dropdown';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/modal';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/popover';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/scrollspy';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/tab';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/tooltip';
// import 'bootstrap/js/src/util';
```

There is no need to do anything like below:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

I am a `vue.js` developer and in new `vue-cli-3`, we create `vue.config.js` in root and place code like above to register new plugin, but as said there is no need to do all this in `bootstrap": "^4.1.1"`.

Bootstrap's tooltip plugin is depend on `popper.js` and need to be enabled manually, so you can do like below in the component where you use tooltip element:

```
<script>
  import $ from 'jquery';

  export default {
    mounted() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    },
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue, and the solution is described here: https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/287

My `main.ts` now looks like something like the following:

```
import "jquery";
import Popper from "popper.js";

(<any>window).Popper = Popper;

require("bootstrap");
```

And I had to run `npm install @types/requirejs --save` to get the call to `require` working.

EDIT: I totally missed this the first time around, but the documention actually has a better way to solve this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/

```
plugins: [
  ...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
    Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
    Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
    ...
  })
  ...
]
```

Comment: Your solution wasn't working at first, the biggest reason was that I had to remove Popper completely from the `webpack.config.js`. Can you please mention it in your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Found how to correctly do it directly in the webpack.config, I actually found it by luck while browsing new Bootstrap 4 documentation in their getting started section. So I actually answered my own question but still upvoted yours because that helped me understand the real issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.net Core 2 project add the following scripts to  of main HTML file  ("_Layout.cshtml" file)

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/popper.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For me it's working.