# Bootstrap 4 error "Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js", with Aurelia CLI and Require.js

Tags: typescript, requirejs, bootstrap-4, aurelia

I'm having trouble configuring Bootstrap 4 beta in an Aurelia CLI app (v0.31.1) with requirejs and using TypeScript. After having tried several config variations I keep on getting the following console error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js

Here are the steps to reproduce. First, install the packages:

```
$ npm install --save jquery bootstrap@4.0.0-beta popper.js
```

Next, I've configured **aurelia.json**:

```
  "jquery",
  {
    "name": "popper.js",
    "path": "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd",
    "main": "popper"
  },
  {
    "name": "bootstrap",
    "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
    "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
    "deps": [
      "jquery",
      "popper.js"
    ],
    "exports": "$",
    "resources": [
      "css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
  }
```

Notice in the config above that:

- popper.js is registered before bootstrap
- the UMD module is used
- popper.js is set as a dependency for bootstrap, next to jquery

Finally, in my **app.ts**:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

With this configuration, building using `au build` works fine. But upon running, using `au run --watch` I get the following console errors:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org) (defaults.js:19)
>   Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org) (bootstrap.min.js:6)
>   ... a bit further on:
>   Uncaught TypeError: plugin.load is not a function at Module. (defaults.js:19)

Unfortunately, the Bootstrap 4 docs only mention [instructions on webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/). So does a search on both Aurelia's [Gitter.im channel](https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss) and on StackOverflow. I cannot find samples regarding Aurelia CLI with Require.js. Finally, Google hits shows only examples for embedding the alpha versions (which relied on 'tethering' rather than 'popper').

Similar questions on SO, which have the same error but aren't applicable to my situation:

- [Bootstrap 4 Beta importing Popper.js with Webpack 3.x throws Popper is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645971/bootstrap-4-beta-importing-popper-js-with-webpack-3-x-throws-popper-is-not-a-con)
- [Angular 4 Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680644/angular-4-bootstrap-dropdown-require-popper-js)
- [And several more...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Bootstrap+dropdown+require+Popper.js)

So, my question: how can I configure Bootstrap 4 with Popper.js in an Aurelia CLI app (using Require.js, not Webpack)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Popper replaced Tether in the beta.

As such you will need to swap out tether with popper (or just add it if you never had the alpha) to the prepend section of your aurelia.json file. (Make sure you link to the UMD version seen below)

```
"prepend": [
   ...
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
   ...
     ]
```

You will also need the bundling as expected, something like this:

```
      {
        "name": "bootstrap4",
        "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
        "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
        "deps": [
          "jquery"
        ],
        "exports": "$",
        "resources": [
          "css/bootstrap.css"
        ]
      }
```

## =Addendum=

Unlike tether, popper does not need to be prepended it seems.
So you could include it like any other dependency with

```
 {
     "name": "popper.js",
     "path": "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd",
     "main": "popper.min"
 },
```

Comment: Awesome, adding the "prepend" indeed works, even without altering my original bundling. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure you'll want popper in the bundling as well as you will be including it twice.

Comment: This is awesome thanks for the question and for the reply!

Comment: I've followed these instructions to the letter, and no longer get the jQuery is nor defined error.  However, I now get `Uncaught TypeError: Popper is not a constructor`. In my `main.ts` I have included 
`import "jquery";
import * as Popper from "popper.js";
(<any>window).Popper = Popper.default;
import "bootstrap";
`
This is using aurelia-cli.

Comment: You definitely targeting the UMD version of popper? it lives in a different folder.

Comment: This is not working for me, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`. I assume this `prepend` business is more of a workaround rather than how it's supposed to work?

Comment: In prepend, make sure tu add popper.js before require.js.

Comment: @JeremyHolt ever get it working? Currently I'm getting the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

I uninstalled popper.js and used the version built into bs4 by using `js/bootstrap.bundle.min` instead of `js/bootstrap.min`

```
  "jquery",
  {
    "name": "bootstrap",
    "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
    "main": "js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
    "deps": ["jquery"],
    "exports": "$",
    "resources": [
      "css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I find this the easiest way to solve the problem. Note to other readers: in the zipfile they are providing for download (currently) the file is "`bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`"

Comment: Solved my problem as well. Just reference "bootstrap.bundle.min.js"

Answer (score 5):

Add in your code.

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This answer helped, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Using the bundled version of BS4 worked for me as follows :-

Remove popper `npm uninstall popper.js`

Update to BS4 or later `npm install bootstrap --save`

Make sure jquery is installed `npm install bootstrap --save`

Edit `.angular-cli.json' to include jquery and bundled BS4

```
   "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
   ],
```

Comment: How do you reference Popper in your files?

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC change reference from bootstrap to bootstrap.bundle

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js",
                       "~/Scripts/respond.js"
                ));'

Answer (score 0):

as of final bootstrap 4.0 below is the working conf for bootstrap with popper

```
//file; aurelia_project/aurelia.json
"dependencies": [   
    ...
    ... // other dependencies
    ...

   "text",
   "jquery",
   {
     "name": "popper.js",
     "path": "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd",
     "main": "popper.min"
   },
   {
     "name": "bootstrap",
     "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
     "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
     "deps": ["jquery"],
     "exports": "$",
     "resources": [
       "css/bootstrap.css"
     ]
   },
...
... // remaining dependencies
...
],
```

This works with latest aurelia & bootstrap (as of 2018-Feb) without using the prepend method

Answer (score 0):

With the new bootstrap 4 you can just include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
</script>
```

Popper.js is already included in this file. Check bootstrap documentation dropdowns:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#overview

PS: You need to install bootstrap 4 ofcourse! It might not be exactly your answer but it might help alot for other people who aren't using Aurelia CLI and Require.js